# Does this bijective function satisfy these properties?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have the following question

> Let A, B ⊆ N and |A| = |B| = |N|, where N is the set of natural
>   numbers. Prove that |A U B| = |N| by constructing a bijective
>   function, F: A U B → N.

Since I know |A| = |B| = |N| I can say that |A| -> |B| -> |N| and that since they are all the same one given relation could be |x| = |x| = |x|.

By two theorems in my book that state if F: X -> Y, G: Y -> Z are both onto or one to one then the composition g ∘ f is onto or one to one, respectively.

By composition of functions I have the following

**(g ∘ f)(x1) = (g ∘ f)(x2) = x3**

**g(f(x1)) = g(f(x2)) = x3**

**f(x1) = f(x2) = x3** ; g is onto and one to one

**x1 = x2 = x3** ; f is onto and one to one

**|x1| = |x2| = |x3|** ; Need to restrict the domain and range to positive 
numbers and 0

**|x1| = |x3|**

I wrote this down as my solution but I was marked wrong for an unknown reason. Can someone point out why please, and perhaps suggest a way to find a better answer?

EDIT: All I know is what is written in the question. The homework this was written on was not returned so I don't what part specifically he had an issue with or what my answer was verbatim. If you think this is correct, please just say so.

Comment: What does $|N|$ mean? Do we know that $A, B$ and $N$ are countable?

Comment: I believe he means N  is the set of natural numbers. He didn't specify. All I know is what is written in the question.

Comment: It seemed kind of strange to me to since the absolute value of N is still just N anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You did not show that $|A\cup B|=|N|$, but you showed that if $|A|=|N|$ and $|B|=|A|$, then also $|B|=|N|$. Note that $|\cdot|$ does not refer to the absolute value of a number, but probably to the cardinality of a set. Which means that, by definition, $|X|=|Y|$ iff there exists a bijective function $f:X\rightarrow Y$.

Here's how to approach the actual task: Since the cardinalities of $A$ and $B$ coincide with those of $N$, by definition, there exist bijective functions $f:A\rightarrow N$ and $g: B \rightarrow N$. This means for an element of $A$, $f$ tells the 'index number' of that element if you think of $A=\{a_1,a_2, \dots\}$, i.e. $f(a_n)=n$.

The following works for $A\cap B = \emptyset$, for an nonempty intersection you're going to have to amend the argument depending on the cardinality of  $A \setminus B$ and/or $B \setminus A$.

Now define $h(x)=\begin{cases}2f(x) & \mbox{ if } x \in A\\2g(x)+1 & \mbox{ if } x \in B\end{cases}.$

$h$ is defined on $A\cup B$ and maps to $N$.

Firstly, since $A\cap B = \emptyset$, $h$ defines a function.

We see that $h$ surjective (onto) the following way: Let $k \in N$, then $k$ is either even or odd. If $k$ is even, then $k=2n$ for some $n \in N$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=n$. Hence, $h(a)=2f(a)=2n=k$. Similarly, if $k$ is odd, then $k=2n+1$ for some $n\in N$. Since $g$ is surjective, there exists some $b \in B$ such that $g(b)=n$. Hence, $h(b)=2g(b)+1=2n+1=k$. Thus, we have found a preimage for every $k \in N$ and $h$ is onto.

We see that $h$ is injective (one-to-one) the following way: Let $x_1, x_2 \in A \cup B$ such that $h(x_1)=h(x_2)$. If this number is even, then $x_1,x_2 \in A$ (otherwise they are in $B$). This is due to $A\cap B = \emptyset$. So we have $2f(x_1)=h(x_1)=h(x_2)=2f(x_2)$, i.e. $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Since $f$ is one-to-one, we see that $x_1=x_2$. For the case that $x_1,x_2\in B$, we get the equalitiy in a similar way from the injectivity of $g$. Thus, $x_1=x_2$ and $f$ is indeed one-to-one.

This shows that $h$ is bijective.

Comment: I would need to show onto and one to one. I can show one-to-one using the composition of functions method above and I can show by finding an element x of (g ∘ f)(x) = z, right? How did you define those functions?

Comment: @LegionDaeth I'm not sure how the composition of functions part would help you. I got these function from the functional definition of cardinality ($|X|=|Y|$ iff there exists some bijective function $f:X\rightarrow Y$), which is implied in your question, but I assume that this task wasnt given in vacuum, but in context with some lecture/text book where $|\cdot\|$ was defined.

Comment: @Roland It's to show bijectivity. If I can show f(x) and g(x) are onto and one-to-one I can show that they are bijective.

Comment: @LegionDaeth you dont need to show bijectivity for $f$ and $g$. If $|A|=|N|$, then there exists a bijective function $f: A \rightarrow N$.  If $|B|=|N|$, then there exists a bijective function $g:B \rightarrow N$.